# illumination correction or background subtraction in R

Tags: r, image-processing

I am having one image with illumination gradient. I need to do illumination correction before the thresholding. Is there any easy way to do the illumination correction in R or any easy maths? EBImage package doesn't have functionality for this.

Comment: Could you add an example of the image and maybe an example of the desired output?

Comment: it is a cancer fish image from microscope. Some restrictions to add those images. for example https://clouard.users.greyc.fr/Pantheon/experiments/illumination-correction/index-en.html.

Comment: Is your gradient always linear and always horizontal (or vertical)? In that case a simple linear regression should be enough to solve the problem.

Comment: no it is not always linear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is called flatfield correction. Basically, you multiply your image by :

```
correctionMatrix = mean(flatfieldImage) / flatFieldImage
```

where `flatfield` is an image with only the background (your gradient) and `mean(flatfield)` is the mean of your flatfield image (a scalar). If you do the element-wise division, `correctionMatrix` will be lower than 1 for high intensity background, and over 1 for lower intensity background. The multiplication between correctionMatrix and your image will have a fairly uniform background, and thresholding should work.

If you don't have access to a background image (your gradient only), then you can smooth your image enough to get only the gradient. It's less precise, but should work also.